# Firebase data not retrieved in textview

Tags: android, firebase, textview, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

New to Android and Firebase, Developed two application in which one will send the data to the firebase database and other will retrieve the data from the database.

Data is successfully added in firebase console but when I am retrieving the data in other application only one node of the data is displayed, but when I am checking through debugging the code all the data is displayed but in textview only a  single node is displayed.

Below is my code for retrieving the code -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

TextView tv,tv1;
Button btn;
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        // Not in crash process.  Do your Remote Config init here.
        System.out.println("ss");
    }

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        String string = "Name: " + user.getUsername() + "\n Number : " + user.getNumber() + "\n Age: " + user.getAge();
                        tv.setText(string);


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

}
```

Now what I want to do is display all the data in different textviews (one user one textview) or can use cardview(still got to study that).

Below is the json of data on firebase console

```
{
"users" : {
"Name1" : {
  "age" : "18",
  "number" : "1234678",
  "username" : "Name1"
},
"Name2" : {
  "age" : "20",
  "number" : "99999999",
  "username" : "Name2"
},
"Name3" : {
  "age" : "22",
  "number" : "8888888",
  "username" : "Name3"
}
}
}
```

In output on application, I am only getting -

```
Name: Name3
Number: 8888888
Age: 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dynamically create TextView with next data in loop where you going over elements:

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) ...
```

and add this TextView to layout.

If you want to show in one TextView change your code:

```
String string = "Name: " + user.getUsername() + "\n Number : " + user.getNumber() + "\n Age: " + user.getAge();
tv.setText(string);
```

To:

```
String string = tv.getText() + "\nName: " + user.getUsername() + "\n Number : " + user.getNumber() + "\n Age: " + user.getAge();
tv.setText(string);
```

Comment: That works, can you also guide how to display the data in different card views

Comment: 1. Create separate XML layout with CardView and TextView inside.
2. Add Empty LinearLayout (vertical orientation) in your activity
3. Inflate your XML layout with CardView and TextView (Google how to programtically inflate View from XML)
4. Set text to your TextView in inflated cardView
5. Call on your LinearLayout from Activity .addView(cardViewInflated)
6. Steps 3 - 5 repeat in loop instead of calling setText like you do now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having is because you're overwriting your textview with every new snapshot.

One way to solve it is to create more textviews programmatically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length of your list ; i++) {
        final TextView valueTV = new TextView("yourActivity");
        valueTV.setText(string);
        valueTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        valueTV.setTextSize(20);
    }
```